# find all cpp files and list only those files with names that match a pattern (regex) does not work

Tags: bash, find, grep

I have a whole repository of files and I am trying to get a list of files that match a certain criteria.

For example, let us say that I want to take all the files that have the string `foo1` and `foo2/foo3` in the path and do not have `bar1` or `bar2/bar3`. Note that it is possible for `bar1` or `bar2/bar3` to be a sub directory of `foo*` and in that case those directories should also be **excluded**. I tried the following method:

```
IN_REGEX="$1"
OUT_REGEX="$2"

find . -name '*'.cpp | grep $IN_REGEX | grep -v $OUT_REGEX
```

I call this script in this way:

```
 ./script "/foo1/\|/foo2\/foo3/" "/bar1/\|/bar2\/bar3/"
```

However, the loop never gets executed.  I tried changing the `"` in the command line arguments to `'`. But that did not help. I tried changing the `grep`s to `sed` commands like so:

```
find . -name '*'.cpp | sed "\m%$IN_REGEX%" | sed "\%$OUT_REGEX%d"
```

Again, no success. However, when I try to execute the `grep` on the bash shell directly. It works fine.  I have spent the whole day today trying to figure this out.

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams to work fine if you remove the " line 1 and 2 when you are receiving the arguments :

```
IN_REGEX=$1
OUT_REGEX=$2

find . -name '*'.cpp | grep $IN_REGEX | grep -v $OUT_REGEX
```

Comment: Quotes won't make a difference there in any Bourne-like shell let alone bash. More likely there was some invisible character like a carriage return after the quote. You need quotes around `$IN_REGEX` and `$OUT_REGEX` though (and `--` to mark the end of options or use the `-e` option to grep). You might want the `-E` option so you can replace your `\|` (which by the way is not standard) with `|` (which is standard).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `!`(negate) and `-path` command-switches of `find` to accomplish this

```
$ find . \( ! -path "*bar*" -a ! -path "*bar2\/bar3*" -a -path "*foo*" -print \)
```

This will search in folders excluding `bar`, `bar2/bar3`, and including folders with `foo` in path. Give this a try. The syntax might change with different versions of `find` command.

[Refer find man page for more details](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find).