# echo string >> file does not work

Tags: bash, io-redirection, echo

I wrote the following script:

```
for filename in `find . -name '*'.cpp | grep $IN_REGEX | grep -v $OUT_REGEX`
do
    echo "Output file is $OUTPUT_FILE"
    count=`git log --pretty=format: --name-only $filename | grep -v ^$ | wc -l`
    echo "$count    $filename" >> $OUTPUT_FILE
done
```

But nothing gets written into the output file.

Please note:

1. I have set the values for `OUTPUT_FILE`, `IN_REGEX` and `OUT_REGEX`.
2. The code inside the loop is being executed. I checked this with an `sh -x` invokation.
3. When I remove the `>> $OUTPUT_FILE` I get the output.
4. I tried a `touch $OUTPUT_FILE` inside the script and that is working fine.

Can someone please point out what is my mistake here?

Comment: Can you move the `>>$OUTPUT_FILE` to the end of the loop, i.e. `done >>$OUTPUT_FILE`?

Comment: maybe you dont have permission on the dir to redirect the file. So you maybe running it as sudo. sudo touch will work. but sudo echo "string" >> log.txt wont work. Can you add the permission in that dir to the question and how you are running the script.

Comment: Ashwin, even a normal touch is working. Did not need a sudo

Comment: From your two recent questions, I'd bet your script has some carriage return characters as if coming from a system where line ending is with CRLF. Try `dos2unix` or `d2u` on the files to convert to Unix line ending. See the output of `cat -vte` on the file to confirm.

Comment: Stephane, my script does not use any input files. All the values required (IN_REGEX, OUT_REGEX and OUTPUT_FILE) are set in the script itself. There seems to be something that is preventing this script from writing to the filesystem. I have checked the permissions, the space availability and also if `touch` works. All three don't show any problem.

Comment: I mean the script itself contains CRs

Comment: Add `set -x` at the head of the script just below the `#!/bin/bash` line) to see a trace of what the script is doing.

Comment: Tried with `set -x` the code is going into the loop and the `echo` is also being executed. In fact, when I remove the redirection, I am able to see the output on the screen.

Comment: I tried redirecting the output to a different directory and it is working fine. Seems to be something about this directory? Here are the permissions on this directory:
`drwxr-xr-x`
Doesn't seem wrong to me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Does $OUTPUT_FILE exist? What are its permissions (`ls -l $OUTPUT_FILE`, `getfacl $OUTPUT_FILE`)? How many times is the `echo "Output file..."` executed? (I'd put that one outside the `for`, but it's your call)?

(I'm suspecting your `find ...` pipeline doesn't return anything)

Comment: I tried with and without the file. Also with an echo outside the loop. It did not work as expected. A touch works anywhere though.

Comment: Again, this just means that your loop just does nothing. Something _this_ fundamental isn't broken.

Comment: Perhaps you have the same mistake as [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66524/find-all-cpp-files-and-list-only-those-files-with-names-that-match-a-pattern-re) in setting the regexps?

Comment: -rw-r--r-- These are the permissions on the file and the ownership is with my account.

Comment: By the way, the other question was also mine. Something that I resolved by removing the `"` around the REGEX values.

Comment: @KarthickS Removing those `"` makes no difference to the script you've posted. A hidden character such as a CR, also present here after `$OUTPUT_FILE`, is a likely explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas that might help you troubleshoot this:

- Rather than redirect stanard out to a the file, pipe it to `tee` and include your file. Hopefully you should see the output on stdout (as well as have it go to $OUTPUT_FILE). E.g.:

  echo "$count    $filename" | tee $OUTPUT_FILE
- Use an absolute path for $OUTPUT_FILE, not a relative path so that it's not dependent on where you invoke the script.  If you're using relative you may not be looking in the right place for the output file.
- Continue to invoke the script with -x so you can see exactly what's going on when you run it.  Make sure the value of $OUTPUT_FILE is set at the time of redirection.
- If you're not committed to using sh, you could try your script in bash.  You could then make use of some of the bash options using the set builtin (see `help set`). When developing a script it can be useful to do a 'set -e' to have the script exit if something returns a non-zero exit status.  You might also need to play with the status of pipefail.  So to help debug you could put this at the top of your script:

  ```
  set -x
  set -e
  # Optionally:
  set -o pipefail
  ```